# preg_match function doesn't work correctly in certain PHP script

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-match, unicode-normalization

I am using preg_match function to filter unwanted characters from a textarea form in 2 PHP scripts I made, but in one of them seems not to work.

Here's the script with the problem:

```
<?php
    //Database connection, etc......

    mysql_select_db("etc", $con);
    $errmsg = '';
    $chido = $_POST['chido'];
    $gacho = $_POST['gacho'];
    $maestroid = $_POST['maestroid'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comment'];
    $voto = $_POST['voto'];

    if($_POST['enviado']==1) {
        if (preg_match ('/[^a-zA-Z áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]/i', $comentario))
            $errmsg = 1;
        if($errmsg == '') {
            //here's some queries, etc
        }
    }

    if($errmsg == 1)
        echo "ERROR: You inserted invalid characters...";
?>
```

So as you can see the preg_match just filter unwanted chracters like !"#$%&/() etc..

But every time I type a special character like 'ñ' or 'á' it triggers the error code.

I have this very similar script that works perfectly with the same preg_match and filters just the unwanted characters:

```
//Database connection, etc..
mysql_select_db("etc", $con);
$errmsg = '';

if ($_POST['enviado']==1) {
     $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
     $apodo = $_POST['apodo'];
     $mat1 = $_POST['mat1'];
     $mat2 = $_POST['mat2'];
     $mat3 = $_POST['mat3'];

     if (preg_match ('/[^a-zA-Z áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]/i', $nombre))
         $errmsg = 1;


     if($errmsg == '') {
         //more queries after validation
     }
}

if($errmsg == 1)
    echo "ERROR: etc......."
?>
```

So the question is, what am I doing wrong in the first script??

I tried everything but always fails and shows the error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Print the value of `$comentario` before you test it with `preg_match`, make sure it contains what you think it contains. We can't debug this for you without knowing the inputs you're using.

Comment: I echo'd the variable before and after the first IF and prints exactly what I typed, included the 'ñ' etc.

Also, when I add things to the preg_match like 0-9 seems to make the correct changes and doesn't filter the numbers, the only problem actually happens just with the special characters like 'ñ'.

Comment: it might have to do with different characters sets on the client and in your source.

Comment: @jcomeau I missed that the '^' at the start of the character class, thanks for pointing that out, my answer didn't make much sense.

Comment: I added this to the form <form accept-charset="utf-8">. Now seems to work, very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets

Answer (score 1):

try adding a u at the end along with your i to use unicode

```
/[^a-zA-Z áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]/iu
```

Comment: $nombre = "(adsfá";
if (preg_match ('/[^a-zA-Z áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]/iu', $nombre))
    echo "match!";

works for me...

Comment: Yes, it works, but now accepts any character, like !"#$%&/()=? etc. I don't want those characters.

Answer (score 1):

Hi before i was using this match expression:

```
/^[a-z]\d_]+$/i
```

because i was accepting letters from a to z, digits from 0 to 9 and underscore '_', the plus sign '+' to repeat through the whole string, and the '/i' for insensitive match. But i needed to accept the 'ñ' letter.

So, what i tried and worked for me was using this regex:

```
/^[a-z\d_\w]+$/iu
```

I added '\w' to accept any word character and also added an 'u' after '/i' to treat the pattern as UTF-16 character set, instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the form.

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8">.
```

Now seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you specifying `/i` yet enumerating all the upper‐ and lower‐case letters separately?

**ALSO:** This won’t work at all if you don’t normalize your input. Consider how `ñ` can be either character U+F1 *or* characters U+4E followed by U+303!

- *Unicode Normalization Form D* will guarantee that both U+F1 and U+4E,U+303 turn into the canonically decomposed form U+4E,U+303.
- *Unicode Normalization Form C* will guarantee that both U+F1 and U+4E,U+303 turn into form U+4E because it uses canonical decomposition followed by canonical composition.

Based on your pattern, it looks like you want the NFC form.

From PHP, you’ll need to use the [`Normalization` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) on these to get it working reliably.

Comment: I know the /i is useless in the example, but was just for demonstration purposes (doesn't affect my preg_match at all). Anyway, I already fixed the problem adding to my html form <form accept-charset="utf-8">. I don't know why this fixed the problem, the other form I am using with the second script doesn't have this attribute and works without problem.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this can help but i had exactly the same problem with those kind of special characters and that turned me crazy for many days at the end i understood that the problem was a html_entities() command sanitizing the string before running in preg_match(), moving the html_entities() after prey_match()made it work great.